# Retrieve same set cell values across multiple tabs from new spreadsheets and formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Need to copy and paste set cells data from multiple business entity spreadsheets and match format of master spreadsheet.

Need to copy and paste set cells within each tab on workbook and populate a master spreadsheet with the data in a specific format - So I'll be looking to copy the same cells from new workbooks each time.  (Sheet 1 = Account,  C2, C6. Sheet 3 = Pricing and commission, B5, B7 and so on) and then auto format it into the master spreadsheet layout.

This looks the closest to my need but unsure of how to tailor it.

```
    Sub Consolidate()

Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
Dim originsheet As Worksheet
Dim destsheet As Worksheet
Dim ResultRow As Long
Dim Fname As String
Dim RngDest As Range


    Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set RngDest = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                       .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xlsx")

    'loop through each file in folder (excluding this one)
    Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name

        If Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

            Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
            Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            With RngDest
                .Cells(1).Value = originsheet.Range("E9").Value
                .Cells(2).Value = originsheet.Range("D18").Value
                .Cells(3).Value = originsheet.Range("D22").Value
                .Cells(4).Value = originsheet.Range("E11").Value
                .Cells(5).Value = originsheet.Range("F27").Value
            End With

            wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
            Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0)

        End If

        Fname = Dir()     'get next file
    Loop
End Sub


Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
    For Each ws in wkbkorigin.Worksheets '### YOU NEED TO ITERATE OVER SHEETS IN THE WORKBOOK THAT YOU JUST OPENED ON THE PRECEDING LINE
        With ws
            ' Do something with the ws Worksheet, like take the values from D3 and E9 and put them in your RngDest range:
             RngDest.Cells(1,1).Value = .Range("D3").Value
             RngDest.Cells(1,2).Value = .Range("E9").Value
        End With
        Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0) '## Offset this range for each sheet so that each sheet goes in a new row
    Next
    wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
    Fname = Dir()     'get next file
```

My vba knowledge is very limited so any advice would be much appreciated. Would I need to save each business entity spreadsheet before running macro? Previously I just extract what I need and close out.  Apologies for the length of question.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed for being too broad. Narrow it down to a specific task. Do you need to loop through a folder, do you have problems knowing how to copy and paste? Etc

Comment: The Excel-vba tag is pending deletion. it will be replaced by the combination of Excel and vba tags.

Comment: @Wolfaloo I will believe it when I see it.  They have been arguing that for longer than I have been a member.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Transfer_Data()
On Error Resume Next
        Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
        Dim wbSource As Workbook
        Dim wsSource As Worksheet
        Dim intChoice As Integer
        Dim strPath As String

        'turn off screen blinking to make code faster and less annoying
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Set the wsMaster to the sheet you want to add data to
        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        'only allow the user to select one file
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
        'make the file dialog visible to the user
        intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
        'determine what choice the user made
        If intChoice <> 0 Then
            'get the file path selected by the user
            strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
            'open the file
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
        End If
        'Then you would loop through each worksheet like this and copy whatever information you want to wherever you want on your original sheet
        For Each wsSource In wbSource.Worksheets
            'set the values of the cells equal to its corresponding cell in the opened worksheet (copy and paste will be slower and more of a hassle unless you want cell color etc also)
            'format of cells: .cells('rownubmer', 'colnumber')
            wsMaster.Cells(3, 2).Value = wsSource.Cells(1, 2).Value
        Next
        'close file without saving
        wbSource.Close (False)
        'turn screen updating back on
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'goto master sheet
        wsMaster.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: This is above and beyond, thank you. Works perfectly and I've learned a lot. Thanks again.